# Are there any performance tests available re Direct2D?

Tags: windows, gdi+, gdi, direct2d

I'm particularly interested in drawing primitives performance (CAD, GIS, etc.) but any speed comparison with GDI/GDI+ would be very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put in some code to output how long it took for the test to run, then you can just compare the performance of various methods.

Comment: My point is that comparisons depend heavily on hardware, as well as what is being done in the drawing, such as how many triangles or squares are being drawn, for example.  The best way is to actually try to time various methods and see the numbers are.